# How to plot bars from pandas value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have used the pandas value_counts function to provide counts of unique values:

```
CountStatus = pd.value_counts(df['scstatus'].values, sort=True)

Output:
200    133809
304      7217
404      2176
302       740
500       159
403         4
301         1
dtype: int64
```

I now want to plot these values using matplotlib i.e `plt.barh(CountStatus)`, however I keep getting the `error: ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'width' must be length 7 or scalar`.

I'm guessing this may have something to do with the left hand column being an index column. Is there a way around this to obtain a horizontal bar chart? Do I need to convert it or specify something else in the function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Update

- [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) is a `Series` method

  - Use `normalize=True` to get the relative frequencies, and multiply by 100 , `.mul(100)`, for percent, if needed.
- Plot with [`pandas.Series.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) with `kind='bar'` or `kind='barh'`

```py
import seaborn as sns

# test data, loads a pandas dataframe
df = sns.load_dataset('planets')

# display(df.head(3))
            method  number  orbital_period  mass  distance  year
0  Radial Velocity       1         269.300  7.10     77.40  2006
1  Radial Velocity       1         874.774  2.21     56.95  2008
2  Radial Velocity       1         763.000  2.60     19.84  2011

# plot value_counts of Series
ax = df.method.value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

### Original Answer

I think you can use [`barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.barh.html):

```
CountStatus.plot.barh()
```

Sample:

```
CountStatus = pd.value_counts(df['scstatus'].values, sort=True)
print CountStatus
AAC    8
AA     7
ABB    4
dtype: int64

CountStatus.plot.barh()
```

[image: graph]