# Trying to get a two column data set from .value_counts(), instead I get one

Tags: python, pandas

**I am unique values from a very long list. For example**

```
Column_1
apple
orange
pear
banana
pear
apple
apple
```

**if I type:**

```
file['Column_1'].value_counts()
```

it returns a single column

```
apple 3
pear 2
orange 1
banana 1
```

**I would like to to be two columns so I use matplotlib to graph the results.**

```
apple, 3
pear, 2
orange, 1
banana, 1
```

**Any advice?**

Comment: The return from `value_counts` is a `Series` I would recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686321/15497888) which can handle both renaming the column and turning it back into a DataFrame. `file['Column_1'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Counts')`

Comment: You might also find [Using Pandas Value_Counts and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36762199/15497888)/[Sorted bar charts with pandas/matplotlib or seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28022227/15497888) helpful.